# Баг с MySQL неожидано выключается и не работает, пока не переустановишь дб

Tags: mysql, xampp

Я работаю с XAMPP запускаю Apache и MySQL для работы и тестов, но иногда по какой-то странной мне причине, MySQL сервер просто не запускается, в XAMPP я вижу такое

```
Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:25:32  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
10:25:33  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
10:25:33  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:25:33  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:25:33  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:25:33  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:25:33  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:25:33  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:25:33  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

А переходя в log я вижу такое

```
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 184
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 1169302; transaction id 1506
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-07-10 10:25:56 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

По логам все нормально, в плане нету ошибок, и говорится что вроде все норм запустилось, но НЕТ.

Фиксится это дело, таким способ, удаля все из папки MySQL > data закидывая все файлы, из backup, а после чего, чтобы все прошлые дб остались, из "сломанной data" копировать все папки баз данных, а также файлы остальные файлы, с заменной. ОЧЕНЬ странное поведение не могу понять что за бред, если поможет, у меня установлена Windows 11 Home

Comment: А что Windows Event Viewer показывает?

Comment: Ошибка есть но не знаю что за ошибка
mysqld.exe: Error on close of 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\aria_log_control' (Errcode: 9 "Bad file descriptor") по времени все сходится и по названию тоже :)
Да провел сейчас тест, и заменив именно этот файл, дб заработала нормально!
но почему он ломается?